# Long brown needly things fallen from tree?

Tags: botany, trees

I was walking next to a row of trees (I think coniferous) and found many of these things on the ground:

A parallel bundle of 2-4 medium-brown needly things, about 15 cm long and 1 mm in diameter, not quite as sharp as a saguaro spine, a bit stiffer than a blade of grass, connected at one end by a darker brown bulb about 3 mm in diameter and 7 mm long. Very easy to pull apart.

What is this thing called?

EDIT: thanks to nextworldplz' answer, here's a picture of what I was describing (turns out to be specifically ponderosa pine needles):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... [pine needles](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjF5K2Hov7iAhVIB50JHYK8DfIQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.minnesotawildflowers.info%2Ftree%2Fponderosa-pine&psig=AOvVaw2Hj25fVMtYIBiTNRWdQ4nv&ust=1561333331193197)?

These are the leaves of coniferous (evergreen) trees. It sounds like they might be from *Pinus ponderosa,* a species of pine.

Comment: Yup, I think that's it. lol. I was originally thinking "aren't pine needles shorter?"

Comment: If they are brown, they are dead pine needles.  Unlike deciduous trees, which shed their leaves in the fall and grow new ones in the spring, conifers replace their needles more or less continuously: https://sciencing.com/pine-needles-6455979.html  Needles also vary in length according to the species.